# Javascript: using a while loop to repeat a function

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a collection of divs with the class "Foo" and I want to change the colors of the text incrementally over and over.  Each `forEach` should run this change one time but I need to run the function again to change them again.

If I want to repeat to continually run this function, what are my best options?   Should I throw it in a while loop?

```
    function colorWords() {
        let textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
        let colors = ["yellow","blue","green","red"];

        textBoxes.forEach((word, index) => {
           setTimeout(() => {
             word.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.rand()*colors.length)]
          }, 500 + index*250);

        }, 


    }
```

Comment: You probably need `setInterval()` rather than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You may need setInterval.

Also replace Math.rand() with Math.random()

```js
let colors = ["yellow", "blue", "green", "red"];
let interval
setInterval(() => {
  let textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
  textBoxes.forEach((word, index) => {
    interval = index;
    word.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  }, 500 + interval * 250)
})
```

```html
<div class='foo'>1</div>
<div class='foo'>1</div>
<div class='foo'>1</div>
<div class='foo'>1</div>
<div class='foo'>1</div>
```

Comment: thanks! So can I just wrap what I had in a function called `myFunc` and then do `let interval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000)`  ?...rather than having the setInterval logic inside my function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval to control the loop segment time.  Below I've set intervals to 250ms to get an idea of how frequent the updates occur:

```js
let INTERVAL_IDS = []
document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click',start)
document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click',stop)


function start(){
  let colors = ["yellow", "blue", "green", "red"];
  let textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
  
  INTERVAL_IDS.push(setInterval(function(){
    textBoxes.forEach(word => 
      word.style.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    )
  },250))
}

function stop(){
  clearInterval(INTERVAL_IDS.pop())
}
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button><button id="stop">stop</button>
<span class='foo'>H</span>
<span class='foo'>e</span>
<span class='foo'>l</span>
<span class='foo'>l</span>
<span class='foo'>o</span>
```

Answer (score -3):

Yeah, a while loop with a counter sounds reasonable. All inside of a setInterval function to fire at so many seconds.

````
let counter = 0 
while( counter >= 10){
*your code*;
counter++
}```
````

Comment: you can instead do while(true)

Comment: to avoid infinite loops, how would you set the falsy value here?

Comment: This is also setting infinite loop "counter !== Number". It is never going to be false for any number. Number is a function, what is the point of comparing it with a number

Comment: @KomalBansal Without a break this is going to kill the browser, hard.  Like really really hard.  Memory will shoot up through the roof.  Regardless, this is a bad idea as his is just going to make the colors change really really quickly "Number" amount of times and then stop.

Comment: Sorry, I meant number being a number the OP sets himself. ie 10

Comment: guess people took the 'Number' literally. Will watch out/ refrain from using Number for that in the future